# Can't use folder on secondary drive as volume in Docker Compose due to "Operation not permitted"

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to use a folder on a secondary drive as a volume in Docker Compose.  However, whenever I run `docker-compose up` I get a long error trace, and I believe this is the most relevant part:

```
mongo_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-06T11:17:00.611+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22347,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version. This may be due to an unsupported upgrade or downgrade."}
mongo_1  | {"t":{"$date":"2023-08-06T11:17:00.611+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":28595,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Terminating.","attr":{"reason":"1: Operation not permitted"}}
```

I am on Fedora 38. The drive is mounted according to this fstab line:

`UUID=2C7EF8F27EF8B624    /home/impasse/Main    ntfs    defaults,noatime,uid=1000    0 2`

and is meant to be accessed from both Windows 11 (on which works fine) and from Fedora, which I am setting up right now. Note that I am giving ownership to uid 1000 (which corresponds to my user) because I thought that this was an ownership problem, since by default this folder was owned by Superuser.

I have the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.1"

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - /home/impasse/Main/Documents/Misc/MongoDB/example_db:/data/db

    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: example_username
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example_password
```

This setup works fine if the volume folder is outside /home/Main, say, in /home. But this doesn't work for my use case because I need to access it from both Windows and Linux on different occasions.

What am I missing?